# In Rails 5, How to create a controller action which serves some binary data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, keras, rails-postgresql

Today I am working with Keras.js which has a repo here:

https://github.com/transcranial/keras-js

To operate this I need to serve some JS which looks something like this:

```
const model = new KerasJS.Model({
  filepaths: {
    model: 'url/path/to/model.json',
    weights: 'url/path/to/model_weights.buf',
    metadata: 'url/path/to/model_metadata.json'
  },
  gpu: true
})
```

I want
'url/path/to/model_weights.buf'
to route to a controller action which serves some binary data.

Question 1:
In Rails 5, How to create a controller action which serves some binary data?

After I get the answer to Q1, I will ask:

Question 2:
In Rails 5, How to create a controller action which gets some (small) binary data from a model (backed by Postgres) and then serves the binary data?

I'm tempted to use the info at the URL below but I'd welcome any comments or syntax examples:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data

Answer (score 0):

This was an easy task to figure out:

```
def nnmodel_buf
  # /kpredictions/nnmodel_buf
  send_data Nnmodel.first().nnmodel_buf
end
```